# Why are duplicate activities being created?

Tags: activity

I have a client who has noticed that some activities that they create are being duplicated. I can see solid evidence of exact duplicates - apart from the id in the activity record.  In the activity table the 2 ids are consecutive, in the activity_contact table they are almost consecutive. The contents of the activity records are exactly the same - the created_date and modified_date are the same time to the second.  The client creates a lot of activities - there are about 220K activity rows and they do have quite a few users working simultaneously updating Civi.  This seems like a bug to me - any suggestions as to what else the problem might be?  This installation is running 5.13.5 with Drupal 7.67

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if it's the same problem but it could be the submitOnce problem which has a temporary fix in 5.14.1 and a fuller fix pending but is an easy change you can make:

See https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/14545/files

i.e. remove the "submitOnce" line.

Briefly the popup version of activities conflicts with the extra javascript that submitOnce adds. The problem was reproduced on firefox - just create an activity using the popup version of e.g. a meeting, from the contact's record.

Comment: What's the story behind this fix? I couldn't track it back and anything I could find didn't seem to be relevant to this problem.  Or maybe I was lost in the Git forest...

Comment: I purposely left out the history because it's been flogged to death already, but I'll update the answer a bit.